# Complex mixin for CSS grid

Tags: html, css, sass, mixins

I'm working on creating a complex mixin for using CSS grid. At the moment what I have is a mixin that you pass in the `no of cols`, `row-gap` and `column-gap` and it returns you a blob - code is below.

**NB** `rem()` is a function I'm using to convert `px` to `rem`.

```
@mixin grid($grid-type, $no-of-cols, $row-gap, $columnn-gap: $row-gap) {
  @supports (display: grid) {
    display: grid;
    #{$grid-type}: repeat($no-of-cols, auto);
    grid-gap: rem($row-gap) rem($column-gap);
  }
}
```

This works fine but the problem is if I want a more complex grid, for example, if I want to use the `fr` values in, how would I go about achieving this? I guess I can't really use the same mixin I've got above because that will just split the grid into equal parts as I'm using `repeat($no-of-cols auto)`.

I'd ideally like to do something like the following:

```
@mixin grid($no-of-cols$, $fractions) {
  @supports (display: grid) {
    //Here I want to take the number of $fractions and output something like
    grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr 2fr //if someone had passed in (3, 1, 1, 2)
  }
}
```

So I guess really I'm trying to answer 2 questions;

1) Can I have one mixin/function that outputs both a grid in fractions `(1fr 2fr)` & numbers (using `repeat(3, auto)`
2) Am I making this overly complex and should this really be a function/mixin or even 2 mixins?

============================

UPDATE: So I've updated the initial Sass function so it's usage is now as follows:

`@include('grid-template-columns/rows', 5px, 5px)`

I've also set `$row-gap` to `$column-gap` since if this parameter is left out in pure CSS the browser will just set `grid-column-gap` to be equal to `grid-row-gap` when using the `grid-gap` shorthand. In case anyone needs this in future!

Comment: In the first paragraph, you talk about *rows*, but later it's really *columns*

Comment: @vals sorry my bad, I meant columns, corrected now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so in case anyone needs to use this in the future, this is what I came up with. While it serves its purpose and works it's not exactly what I had in mind. I think maybe as I originally said, I was trying to over-engineer what I was doing, which is now no longer necessary!

**Sass**

```
@mixin grid($grid-type, $args, $row-gap, $column-gap: $row-gap) {
  @supports (display: grid) {
    display: grid;
    #{$grid-type}: #{$args};
    grid-gap: rem($row-gap) rem($column-gap);
  }
}
```

**Explanation**

So you can see from the above, I'm using `$args` which lets you pass a number of parameters. So as I was trying to create a scenario where someone could create a layout using both fractions (`fr`) and equal boxes using (`repeat([num], auto`), this method allows me to pass in both of these.

**Example** usage is as follows:

```
@include grid('grid-template-rows', '1fr 2fr', 10px, 20px);

@include grid('grid-template-columns, 'repeat(3, auto)', 10px, 15px);
```

As you can see this gives the flexibility to create a grid using both `rows` and `columns` so I'd say this works for my scenario. Hope this helps someone in future and it's certainly worked for me.