# Can I use multiple values for one property in Sass?

Tags: html, css, sass, grid-layout

Slightly related to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43091626/complex-mixin-for-css-grid).

Say in Sass, if I wish to use multiple values for one property, is there a way that I can achieve this using a mixin?

**NB:** I know that my usage of `@each` is wrong but this helps to illustrate what I'm trying to do.

So far I have the following

```
@mixin grid-fractions($grid-type, $args) {
  @supports (display:grid) {
    display: grid;    
    #{$grid-type}: @each $args #{$args}fr;
  }
}
```

It's usage is as follows: `@include('grid-template-rows', 2, 1, 1);` And I'd like to get the mixin to output something like this:

```
@supports (display:grid) {
    display: grid;    
    grid-template-rows: 2fr 1fr 1fr;
  }
```

I know that `$args` lets you include multiple values in a mixin but it's obviously not working as I'm probably not using it correctly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not  just `@include('grid-template-rows', '2fr 1fr 1fr');` ?

Or

Include a mixin and pass parameters as an arglist. It can be done different ways depending on what you want.

```
  @mixin grid($template-rows:null,$template-cols:null,$template-areas:null){
    @supports (display:grid) {
      display:grid;
      $grid-rows:();
      $grid-cols:();
      $grid-areas:();

      @each $rows in $template-rows{
        $grid-rows: append($grid-rows, #{$rows}fr);
      }
      @each $cols in $template-cols{
        $grid-cols: append($grid-cols, #{$cols}fr);
      }
      @each $areas in $template-areas{
        $grid-areas: append($grid-areas, #{$areas}fr);
      }
      grid-template-rows:#{$grid-rows};
      grid-template-columns:#{$grid-cols};
      grid-template-areas:#{$grid-areas};
    }
  }
```

```
  html{
    @include grid(1 2 3, 4 5 6, 7 8 9 );
  }
```

```
        /*
          // Outputs:
          @supports (display: grid) {
            html {
              display:grid;
              grid-template-rows: 1fr 2fr 3fr;
              grid-template-columns: 4fr 5fr 6fr;
              grid-template-areas: 7fr 8fr 9fr;
            }
          }
        */
```

Comment: Yeah I could do that, so maybe I'm just trying to over-engineer what I'm doing. The reason that I'm doing this is because I wanted to create just an over-arching mixin that would cover passing in `1fr 1fr` and also `repeat(3, auto)`. Maybe I'm trying to do too much!

Comment: I added some stuff to avoid repeating code. I hope is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately, this doesn't compile because my usage of `@each` is incorrect.

Comment: This is more what you were looking for. You could do it different, like `fr`unit out from the mixin for example, but at least the code keep things more clear.

Comment: This is great, just what I was looking for. You're missing `display:grid` under the `@supports` but other than that this worked for me. It's good that these are optional parameters.

Comment: Ups, `display:grid` added!